# Formatting an integer value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, int

Im obtaining  an `int` value from `UITextField`  `[self.dbRef.text intValue];`

I want to then format that value so I can add a decimal place that precceds the number ie. If `[self.dbRef.text intValue];` returns `4` i need that value to be `0.04`

So far I have tried various ways including

```
    float Y = ([self.dbRef.text intValue]/100);

    slice.value = Y;

    NSLog(@"float Y  value = %f",Y);
```

returns zero

```
    NSString* formatedTotalApplianceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.%@", self.dbRef.text];
    NSLog(@"formated string = %@",formatedTotalApplianceString);

    int totalAppliances = [formatedTotalApplianceString intValue];
    NSLog(@"Resulting int value = %d",[formatedTotalApplianceString intValue]);

    slice.value = totalAppliances;
    NSLog(@"total appliances int value = %d",totalAppliances);
```

returns zero

Comment: Do your users a favor and format the float value using an NSNumberFormatter so it looks as expected based on the user's locale.

Comment: A Good point but the resulting number is not exposed to the user on this occasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing an integer division, so the `0` value is correct in that context as integers cannot represent fractions (unless you're doing fixed point arithmetics, but that's a different can of worms). You need to do a floating point division, for example:

```
float Y = ([self.dbRef.text floatValue]/100.0f);
```

Either the `[self.dbRef.text floatValue]` or the `100.0f` will turn this into a float division, because if the other side would be an `int` it would automatically get casted to a float. But the "best" way is to have both values of the same type.

Comment: Thank you makes sense now, and thanks for the explantion

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
float Y = [self.dbRef.text intValue]/100;
```

to

```
float Y = ((float)[self.dbRef.text intValue])/100;
```

in your first variant.

Dividing int by int returns you int result even if then you assign it to float. 4/100 = 0 in such case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `[self.dbRef.text intValue]/100` is that it's an integer division. It drops the fraction. One way to work around it is to divide by `100.0`:

```
[self.dbRef.text intValue]/100.0
```

However, this is not the most efficient way of doing it if all you need is adding a zero in front of a fraction: you could avoid `float` altogether by padding your printed `int` to two positions with leading zeros:

```
// If text is 4, the code below prints 0.04
NSLog(@"0.%02d", [self.dbRef.text intValue]);
```

Comment: Ah thank you and thats a much more efficient way of doing it.  Printing it works fine but how do I add that to my `slice.value` I cant seem to work out how to add formatiing to a int value ie slice.value = (@"0.%02d", [self.dbRef.text intValue]); returns experession unused

Comment: @JSA986 If you need to make a string out of it, use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.%02d", [self.dbRef.text intValue]]`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Problem is, it'll work until the integer value exceeds `99` :-)

Comment: Yes of course, I missed the int value off the string, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The first code returns zero because you are performing an integer division, which produces an integer result. You should cast the value to a float.

The second code also returns zero because you're asking for the `intValue` of a floating point value. So the decimal part will be discarded.

`NSString` has also a `floatValue` method, you should use it to get a floating value. Once divided by 100 you will still have a floating point value (in a division if the quotient or the dividend is a float and the other an integer, the integer gets promoted to float):

```
float Y = ([self.dbRef.text floatValue]/100);
slice.value = Y;
```